# How do I downgrade a Homebrewed 3DS from 11.14 to 11.13?

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl, homebrew

My 3DS is set up for homebrew. I saw there was a new software update, and (foolishly) decided to install it. When it came time to restart the system, it gave an error stating:

```
An exception occurred

Processor: Arm11 (core 1)
Exception type: undefined instruction
current process : pm(000000000000000000)
```

crash dump (hex) is:

```
DE C0 AD DE FE CA AD DE 02 00 01 00 0B 00 01 00 01 00 00 00 EC 00 00 00 5C 00 00 00 30 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 F5 1B E0 E0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 17 00 00 00 FE FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 D8 FF FF 0F 2C 0D 10 00 B4 0C 10 00 10 00 00 A0 0F 00 00 00 0C 10 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 EE 6A 9A FA EB 00 30 80 E5 BA 0F 07 EE 9F 1F 92 E1 03 00 51 E1 90 CF 82 01 00 00 5C 03 BA 0F 07 EE 01 30 A0 E1 1E FF 2F 01 F5 FF FF EA E4 62 10 00 F0 00 F0 E7 00 10 00 00 6C 0E 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 50 0E 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CC 0D 10 00 70 6D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I shut down the system, and turned it back on. Same error. I also tried booting it into safe mode with no luck (Same error).

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You want to downgrade the firmware or solve the exception problem?
In my case, I had the system to automatically update the firmware. So, now I am on 11.14 and get the same exception error as yours. Had done the solution provided here: https://github.com/LumaTeam/Luma3DS/issues/1537 and it fixed the problem (replacing the boot.firm and boot.3dsx of Luma3DS v10.2.1 to the root of SD card). But, I am not sure on how to downgrade the firmware though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, you screwed up.
11.14 was targeted to brick consoles with CFW.
If you can get to the chainloader (Start on boot), though, there is hope.
Update the luma boot.FIRM and go back to the scripts in Godmode9 and redump Luma to CTRNAND. That should (hopefully) fix it.

Comment: Welcome! I made the same mistake, you are SO lucky that I know my way around this.

Answer (score 5):

Eris the guest has it right, but for idiots like me, here's a step-by-step (assuming you followed the 3ds hacks guide):

1. Download the latest Luma3ds files onto whatever you use to read/write your SD card (https://github.com/LumaTeam/Luma3DS/releases/tag/v10.2.1)
2. Unzip the files and place the contents of the zip folder  (NOT the folder itself) into the root of the SD card.
3. Put the SD card back into the 3Ds, then boot the chainloader by pressing the power button while holding START.
4. Press HOME, select "Scripts", select "GM9Megascript", select "Scripts from Plailect’s Guide", select "Setup Luma3DS to CTRNAND". Unlock the SD card to do so.
5. Press "B", then select  "Cleanup" the SD card.
6. (May not be necessary) Press "B", select "SysNAND Backup", wait for it to finish, then press HOME and select "Power off" to exit Godmode9 and finish the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issue with the same error for the same reason, last night.

I went to https://github.com/LumaTeam/Luma3DS/releases/tag/v10.2.1 and downloaded the zip file and replaced the boot files on my 3DS sd card (inserted into computer) with the two boot files from the unzipped file. As a precaution I copied all the data from the SD card including the original boot files to my computer before I replaced them.

I then safely ejected the SD card, put it back in the console and followed the Prompt to boot into the main screen (I think I pressed start or A, but it’ll tell you which one) and it started right up like nothing ever happened. The only thing that’s different is I don’t see the Luma splash screen anymore but everything else including godmode works fine